# Question on linear algebra mappings

Tags: linear-algebra, transformation

If $T:R^m\to R^n$ is a linear transformation, show that there is a number $M$ such that $|T(h)|\leq M|h|$ for $h\in R^m$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A$ be the matrix of $T$ in the standard basis. $T(h)=Ah$ write the rows of A which are $a_{i1},..,a_{in}$ as vectors $a_i$ that is $ A=  \begin{pmatrix} a_1 \\ a_2 \\ \vdots \\ a_n \end{pmatrix}$
 then $|Ah| =\sum_{i=1}^n\sqrt{\langle a_{i},h \rangle^2} \le \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n|a_i|^2|h|^2}=|h|\sqrt{|a_1|^2+\dots |a_n|^2} $. So you get $M=\sqrt{|a_1|^2+\dots |a_n|^2}$

Comment: I don't know how this "forum" works.  Do I have to choose the best answer?  If so, how? I think yours is what I was looking for

Comment: There is a small check mark next to the up and downvote arrows. Click it if you think my answer was the most helpful.

Comment: last line should start $|Ah|$, couldn't edit because (for some reason?) edits need to be at least 6 chars. Maybe you can do it?

Comment: @Steven Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

Every **linear transformation** in **finite dimensional** space is **continuous** which means the desired inequality. To find by hand this inequality choose a basis $(e_1,\ldots,e_m)$ of $\mathbb R^m$ and use the uniform norm (since all the norms are equivalent)...

Comment: Yes, it is what I was looking for: showing that every linear transformation between real finite-dimensional vector spaces is uniformly continuous at the point 0 (according to the usual norm topology)

Comment: So if you want a direct proof you can use my hint and tell me if you want a complete proof.

Comment: @Sami this result is usually used to prove the that linear transformations are continuous.

Comment: Yes this is true.@user10444

Comment: No, thanks anyway: I think the other two guys have already given reasonable proofs :)

Answer (score 1):

Note that if $v = \lambda w$, $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$, with $|w| = 1$ then if $|T(w)| \leq M |w|$ you have also $$|T(\lambda w)| = |\lambda||T(w)| \leq M |\lambda w| = M|v|$$ So we can consider $S^{m-1} \subset \mathbb{R}^{m}$.

On $S^{m-1}$ set $$g (w) = \frac{T(w)}{w}$$

This is continous because $T$ is continous by linearity; $S^{m-1}$ is compact and so there exists $M$ such that $$|\frac{T(w)}{w}| \leq M   \ \ \ \forall w \ \in S^{m-1}$$

Then $$|T(v)| \leq M |v| \ \ \ \forall v \ \in \mathbb{R}^{m}$$

Comment: I believe this result is usually needed to show that $T$ is continuous. I have not seen a prove yet that does not use it.

Comment: If you know sum of continuous functions is continuous, and product of continuous functions by a constant is continuous, and the projections onto coordinates are continuous (all easy "by hand"), then you get all linear functions because linear functions are all linear combinations of the projections.  Then WLOG's proof follows.  I think this is a nice way to package the result.

Comment: @StevenGubkin You are right I've forgotten about projections completely, thank you for the reminder.